# AWS SNS signature verification with GO

Tags: go, verification, sign, amazon-sns

I want to implement AWS SNS signature verification in GO. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.verify.signature.html) is the signature verification tutorial provided by AWS.

However, there are some points I can not get it.

> 7: Generate the derived hash value of the Amazon SNS message. Submit the Amazon SNS message, in canonical format, to the same hash function used to generate the signature.

How to derived the **hash value**? Which hash function should I use?

> 8: Generate the asserted hash value of the Amazon SNS message. The asserted hash value is the result of using the public key value (from step 3) to decrypt the signature delivered with the Amazon SNS message.

How to get the **asserted hash value**?

Here is my code, I have a **struct for notification**:

```
type Notification struct {
    Message          string
    MessageId        string
    Signature        string
    SignatureVersion string
    SigningCertURL   string
    SubscribeURL     string
    Subject          string
    Timestamp        string
    TopicArn         string
    Type             string
    UnsubscribeURL   string
}
```

and I've already generated the **canonical string**:

```
    signString := fmt.Sprintf(`Message
%v
MessageId
%v`, self.Message, self.MessageId)

    if self.Subject != "" {
        signString = signString + fmt.Sprintf(`
Subject
%v`, self.Subject)
    }

    signString = signString + fmt.Sprintf(`
Timestamp
%v
TopicArn
%v
Type
%v`, self.Timestamp, self.TopicArn, self.Type)
```

**Decode signature from base64**

```
signed, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(self.Signature)
```

**Get the certificate from .pem**

```
resp, _ := http.Get(self.SigningCertURL)
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
p, _ := pem.Decode(body)
cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(p.Bytes)
```

Now, **how can I verify the signature with my canonical string**? Is the following code right?

```
cert.CheckSignature(x509.SHA1WithRSA, signed, []byte(signString))
```

I always get `crypto/rsa: verification error` from above code.

Thanks!

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/mitchellh/goamz/blob/master/iam/sign.go

Comment: It use version 2 signing process. However, AWS SNS only support version 1 and version 4.

Comment: Have you considered using https://launchpad.net/goamz ?

Comment: Yes, I've used goamz in my other project that use AWS S3. However, the  goamz says that the AWS SNS library is still under developed.

Comment: Right.  It says that the API is not final, but presumably what is there has already solved signing problem you're tackling.

Comment: Would a library like [go-aws-auth](https://github.com/smartystreets/go-aws-auth) help? It signs for both versions 2 and 4 of the signature. Is that what SNS requires?

Comment: @JamesHenstridge IIRC, that sns package has no verification for received message. It only signs the request to AWS, and it only support version 2 signing process.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for your reply, however, AWS SNS's message verification process needs version 1.

Comment: The [AWS SNS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.verify.signature.html) says that verifying the signature of the SNS message is optional, and that either version 1 or version 4 may be used.

Comment: @Matt I noticed that, but I didn't find a way to change the version 1 to version 4 in AWS SNS console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is a really old question, but I had the same problems as the reporter so I took a day to figure this out with the assistance of AWS. I have open sourced my work as an external library, now available [here](https://github.com/robbiet480/go.sns).

You can use it like this (notificationJson is a JSON string):

```
import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"

  "github.com/robbiet480/go.sns"
)

var notificationPayload sns.Payload
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(notificationJson), &notificationPayload)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Print(err)
}
verifyErr := notificationPayload.VerifyPayload()
if verifyErr != nil {
  fmt.Print(verifyErr)
}
fmt.Print("Payload is valid!")
```

Thanks for your initial work on this lazywei, I based my library on your above code!

Answer (score 0):

In the context of this discussion about Amazon SNS message signature verification, it’s also important to notice that Amazon SNS now supports message signatures based on SHA256 hashing:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/09/amazon-sns-supports-message-signatures-based-sha256-hashing/

Here's the launch blog post:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/sign-amazon-sns-messages-with-sha256-hashing-for-http-subscriptions/